# Accessing super class variables/methods in sub class

Tags: java, inheritance, access-modifiers

Since subclass can access super class's variables and methods defined as protected, why following code gives compile error?

```
public class Animal {
    protected int var;

    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Animal eating");
    }
}
class Dog extends Animal {
    Animal an = new Animal();
    an.var = 10;
}
```

Comment: What's the compile error?

Comment: Because you are outside of a method

Comment: **take a hint** : Even if you remove `protected`, you'd still get the error.

Answer (score 1):

**The Problem is not caused** by the fact that `var` is `protected`. It is because you need to *wrap up that line in a method*, like this

```
public Dog(){
    an.var = 10; //Compiles Correctly
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it inside a Method. See below :

class Dog extends Animal {

```
public void testMe()
{
    Animal an = new Animal();
    an.var = 10;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Dog class to have the var attribute set by default, you can use the constructor:

```
public class Dog extends Animal {

    public Dog() {
        this.var=10;
    }
}
```

or use:

```
Dog dog = new Dog();
dog.var=11;
```